# Noindex Only One Subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, noindex

I am having difficulty finding information on how to completely noindex only one particular subdomain via htaccess (from my understanding, that's the best way?) and it is important for me that only that one subdomain and its files are never indexed or crawlable.

I have an Apache server that uses Plesk and the subdomain is for an email software we use for newsletter campaigns etc.

The subdomain is "mail" (e.g https://mail.test.com) and my goal is to only make "mail" noindex because for some reason the software has seo features that can wind up harming our general purpose etc.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I would say the Robots protocol is a better way to declare your subdomain non-crawlable, as I would expect more crawlers to obey it compared to Meta tags. Remember though that Robot files and Meta declarations are option for robots - there are plenty of robots out there that do not pay attention to either.

Answer (score 4):

Create `robots.txt` inside subdomain document root with the following content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```